# How can I change/tranlate the text which I use for sending Facebook application requests based on the target user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, internationalization

I'm using Facebook application requests in my application for users to invite their friends. And I use the 'Message' property to set the application custom message and send the invitation.

I know that once we send the application request, it's up to Facebook to send the original application request and display notification on the target user's profile.

Is it possible to translate the message and display in the target user's notifications (based on the target user's locale or language preference)?

Is there any option in Facebook or any option using [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the receipients user id, you can call graph.facebook.com/friendId and read the locale field and send it based on that.